# How to share NSMutableArray values to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, social-framework

I'm getting values from database and assinging those values to NSMuatbleArray. Then i have sharing array of values into mail. How to share the values with setMessgaeBody:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
 // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
 while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


 sk_code = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];


 NSLog(@"sk_code %@",sk_code);


 [product_sku_array addObject:sk_code];


  // To address
 NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"test@gmail.com"];

 MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

 //  mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 [mailController setSubject:@"Test"];

 [mailController setMessageBody:product_sku_array isHTML:NO];

 [mailController setToRecipients:toRecipents];


 [self presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil];


 }
```

NSLog:

```
product_sku_array (
    123
)

 sk_code test1
 product_sku_array (
    123,
    test1
)
 temp inside is 123,test1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise your array properly and then use

[mailController setMessageBody:[product_sku_array componentsJoinedByString:@","] isHTML:NO];

Comment: I'm getting first value from array only. product_sku_array (
    123,
    test1
)

Comment: I'm getting 123 value only, I didn't get test1

Comment: nsstring* temp = [product_sku_array componentsJoinedByString:@","];

Comment: check temp string and also check your array.

Comment: if temp in fine then use [mailController setMessageBody:temp isHTML:NO];

Comment: check my edited code with NSlog. still i'm getting 123 only in mail..but nslog showing 2 values

Comment: Use [mailController setMessageBody:temp isHTML:NO];

Comment: NSString *temp =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[product_sku_array componentsJoinedByString:@","]];

Comment: Got it..I have to use the value outside loop

Answer (score 0):

`[mailController setMessageBody:]` accepts string parameter, so,

take the NSMutableString and append every array object into your single string

like

> string = [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", [array
>   objectAtIndex:i]]];

then set this string to message body, like,

> [mailController setMessageBody:string isHTML:NO];